# Browser based web Console

Tags: web, interpreter

Do any one know how does the sites like codeacademy.com or runnable.com allows us to execute our code online. Through webserver it even has c++ which can be executed online.

If any one know about it please suggest me some links about it.

and is there any api for those operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how specific sites work, but there are at least two ways:

1) they create an interpreter in javascript for the language, or
2) they pass the code to the server, it executes it, and sends the results back.

Comment: Is there any example links you know.?